# Docker - push from dockerhub to trusted registry?

Tags: ubuntu, docker

I know how to build, tag and push my personal images to my local registry.

But how can I push an image I downloaded via docker_cli from dockerhub into my local registry ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First tag the image downloaded to point it to your registry,

(Below example uses ubuntu image which is already pulled from docker hub)

```
docker tag ubuntu localhost:5000/ubuntu
```

Then, push it to your local registry,

```
docker push localhost:5000/ubuntu
```

Refer https://docs.docker.com/registry/deploying/